# What is 灵恩派 in English?

Tags: translation

福音派 (evangelicalism) and 灵恩派 (?) are constrasted in [this Chinese article](https://www.christiantimes.cn/news/15279/%E5%A6%82%E4%BD%95%E7%9C%8B%E5%BE%85%E7%A6%8F%E9%9F%B3%E6%B4%BE%E4%B8%8E%E7%81%B5%E6%81%A9%E6%B4%BE%E7%9A%84%E5%8C%BA%E5%88%AB%EF%BC%9F).

I was wondering what 灵恩派 is called in English? What denominations in US belong to it, if it exists in US?

I only know the opposite to evangelicalism in US is mainline or liberal Christianity. Is 灵恩派 related to mainline or liberal Christianity?

Answer (score 3):

This comes under what is called "Charismatic Christianity" in English, part of the Pentecostal Movement (五旬節運動/五旬节运动 *Wǔxúnjié yùndòng*).

"Charisma" comes from Koine Greek *χάρισμα* "gift", which in itself is derived from *χάρις* generally translated "grace" in English and 恩 in Chinese. In the New Testament, "charisma" is often used for the gifts of the Holy Spirit, which is often translated 聖靈/圣灵 *shènglíng*.

Hence we have the translation of "charisma" as 靈恩/灵恩 *líng'ēn*, in reference to the religious movement. However, in Chinese translations of the Bible, the Koine Greek *χάρισμα* is generally translated as 恩賜/恩赐 *ēncì* instead, with reference to 禮物/礼物 *lǐwù* too in some footnotes.

Answer (score 1):

[灵恩派](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9D%88%E6%81%A9%E6%B4%BE)（Pentecostal and Charismatic Christianity）是基督新教的一个松散的派别，....

Answer (score 1):

If 灵恩派 = Charismatic = Pentecostalism, there are many such denominations in the US. The largest are the Assemblies of God and the Church of God in Christ, each of which has millions of members.  Also, there is still a large [charismatic movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catholic_Charismatic_Renewal) within the Catholic Church.  There are literally hundreds of other Pentecostal denominations and independent churches.

Comment: Thanks. In US, is "灵恩派 = Charismatic = Pentecostalism" also as conservative as Evangelicalism? I heard Evangelicalism is opposed to Mainline/Liberal Christianity, and wonder what "灵恩派 = Charismatic = Pentecostalism"  opposed to? Is "灵恩派 = Charismatic = Pentecostalism"  not related to Mainline/Liberal Christinaity?